# Constraint linearization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I have the following nonlinear constraint:

$$\sum_{i}\frac{x_{i}}{a_i}>b\left(\sum_{i}x_i\right)^{2},$$

where the $x_i\in[0,1]$-s are decision variables, $b$ and $a_i$, are all positive real numbers.

Can you please help me find a way to make this constraint linear somehow?
Is this even a convex constraint (does it define a convex region)?

Comment: Yes, this is convex.  You can write it as $b(\sum_i x_i)^2 - \sum_i x_i/a_i <0$, where the left-hand-side is a convex function.  It is not linear. You can approximate the nonlinear part by a first order linear expansion about some point, but the affectiveness of that depends on the context.

Comment: It is convex and you can feed it into a QP (quadratic programming) solver or an SOCP (second-order cone programming) solver, both of which there are plenty of.